# how to fetch data from xl sheet in cucumber rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, automated-tests, cucumber

When I do cucumber automation using rails and how to fetch and use data from xl sheet ?
how to fetch data from xl sheet using cucumber rails ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in support for this in Cucumber. You will have to do the reading yourself.

You have to read the xl file from a step or a helper method. A helper method probably makes most sense.

Before you go down this path, consider if it is a problem or not for you to spread the knowledge about what is going on in many places. You have your feature files that contains concrete usage examples and you have xl files with additional data. What prevents you from keeping all of this in the same feature file?